# Cannot compile Scala code using Intellij gradle plugin

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

I am using the Intellij with gradle plugin with gradle wrapper (version = `6.6.1`). If I use Intellij gradle plugin `build` function, it has the following errors (`Could not initialize class sbt.internal.io.Milli$`) during the scala compiling step.

I have tried multiple ways but I still cannot compile the Scala code.

1. Invalidate the IDE cache
2. uninstall and install Scala and gradle plugins
3. remove `~/.gradle/caches` and `~/.gradle/wrapper` folders

In terminal, `./gradlew :dataset:build` works fine but not in Intellij with gradle plugin.
What is the issue with intellij? What other locations I should remove or what settings I should use in Intellij?

```
Task :dataset:compileScala
## Exception when compiling 133 sources to /Users/jh/0_code/alpine-knowledge/alpine-dataset/.out/classes/scala/main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sbt.internal.io.Milli$
sbt.io.IO$.$anonfun$getModifiedTimeOrZero$1(IO.scala:1373)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
sbt.internal.io.Retry$.liftedTree2$1(Retry.scala:38)
sbt.internal.io.Retry$.impl$1(Retry.scala:38)
sbt.internal.io.Retry$.apply(Retry.scala:52)
sbt.internal.io.Retry$.apply(Retry.scala:24)
sbt.io.IO$.getModifiedTimeOrZero(IO.scala:1373)
sbt.internal.inc.caching.ClasspathCache$.fromCacheOrHash$1(ClasspathCache.scala:44)
sbt.internal.inc.caching.ClasspathCache$.$anonfun$hashClasspath$1(ClasspathCache.scala:53)
scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$Map.leaf(ParArray.scala:659)
scala.collection.parallel.Task.$anonfun$tryLeaf$1(Tasks.scala:53)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
scala.util.control.Breaks$$anon$1.catchBreak(Breaks.scala:67)
scala.collection.parallel.Task.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:56)
scala.collection.parallel.Task.tryLeaf$(Tasks.scala:50)
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: are you running Intellij with admin rights ?  Does it compile if you try running with sbt directly? Could the current version of the gradle plugin be incompatible with your current java version or sbt version or even current scala version ?

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip Thanks so much. I spent the whole day to debug this. After I run it as admin rights, it works!!.    The version should have no problem because in terminal it works fine.. Really it is the admin issue. Do you know why we need to use root?  It was working before even without admin rights..

Comment: I think it has to do with not having write privileges in the location where the gradle plugin would built the project, but I could be wrong. Glad it worked! I came up with the idea after reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62523885/2205089